# How to persist data when one property in collection is modifed in mvvm app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have the following model in my mvvm app

```
public class Student: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private string _name;
 public string Name 
 { 
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name"); 
    }
 }

 private bool _isSelected;
 public bool IsSelected 
 {
    get
    {
        return _isSelected;
    } 
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
}
```

And I have the following viewmodel

```
public class StudentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
  private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

  public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
   {
     get 
     {
         return utilslib.Getstudents();
     }
     set
     {
         _students = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Students");
     }
  }
 }
```

I have the following list to which I am binding to Students collection.

```
    <<Button Command="{Binding DeleteSelectedStudentsCommand}" Name="buttontodeletestudents" content ="Delete"/>

     <ListBox Name="studentslist" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Margin="0,0,10,10" >

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <CheckBox Name="hobbycheck" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"

                              IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,ModeTwoWay}" />


                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

In the view model I have the icommand DeleteSelectedStudentsCommand implemented  when user clicks the button"Delete" I want to delete the records for which the IsSelected is set to true and using below statement for the same .

```
 var students = Students.Where( s => s.IsSelected);
```

when the checkbox is checked I get the ischecked event fired in Model class.But when user clicks on Delete button I don't see any of the records for which the checkbox is checked has the isselected set to true  . how do I persist the value of IsSelected property in the collection ?

Comment: So you meant IsSelected property set to true when corresponding item in listbox checked, but then it somehow set back to false, as you said IsSelected property value not persisted?

Comment: Yes @har07.And also when I am trying to execute the statement Students.Where(..) it again fetches the list by calling GetStudents().But before that it should persist the value which it doesn't do that.

Comment: Strange part of your code for me is at the getter of Students property, why is it return utilslib.Getstudents() instead of return _students? and what is utilslib.Getstudents() do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is every time you call Students the getter gives you new collection, and that's why IsSelected property seems like not persisted. You set IsSelected property of Student in one collection, and check the same property in other collection.

This can be confirmed by checking utilslib.Getstudents(). What that method do? Does it really return different ObservableCollection every time it called?

Answer (score 0):

The below updated code has fixed the issue.

```
 private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

 public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
  {
    get 
    {
   if(_students==null)
     return utilslib.Getstudents();
   else
    return _students
 }
 set
 {
     _students = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("Students");
 }
```

}